# low-contrast line detection on noisy photographes

Tags: opencv, line, feature-detection, noise, hough-transform

I'm trying to detect low-contrast lines on photographs of a screen or noisy images in general. I seem to run into two problems:

1. I can't reliably detect the line with an adaptive threshold or edge detection algorithm, because of the noise/dark grid of the screen. Blur seems to help a little, but not enough for me to get it to work.
2. When only a few segments are visible of the same line (due to noise, light conditions or other) I would like to connect the detected line segments to a single straight line.

   ```
    img = cv2.imread("test.jpg")
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray=cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(9,9),0)
    bin = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray2, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 33, 3)
    cv2.namedWindow('Test')
    cv2.imshow("Test", bin)
   ```

I have also experimented with `cv2.Canny` and `cv2.HoughLinesP`, but with no good results, since the dark grid messes up both. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I figure a local version of the threshold function with `THRESH_TRUNCATED` or `THRESH_TOZERO` could help...
filter out the grid. and high-contrast

Since I don't have the reputation to post pictures, I added the links.
Image with a low-contrast line:

[image]

Line detected:

[image]

Comment: Could you edit your question and include a sample image?

Comment: Don't have the rep, but I uploaded them somewhere else and added the links.

Answer (score 1):

Running a Median filter on a large enough window (say 11x11) and then subtracting the average (or a bit less than average) image intensity will make the line easier to detect.

Comment: do you mean the global average or the average of the 11X11 window?

Comment: is there an easy ways to subtract and set all negative to zero?
My for loop is very slow :S
BilateralFiltering after a weak MedianFilter works for filtering out the grid of the LCD screem.

Comment: Nope I can take my sweet time :)